# Is removing duplicates from one list compared to another a NAND operation?

Tags: logic

I have a list like

```
 list1 = {2,3,4,5,9}
```

another list like

```
  list2 = {3,5,10,9}
```

I want some operation (eg. list.Operation(list2)) so that I can get back `list1` as

```
  list1 = {2,4}
```

Is it the same as doing a NAND operation?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++ nor Java nor C. I'd rather tag this as type theory but then again you will get answers you are not going to like.

Comment: Are you interested in an algorithm or in a solution?  In Java, have a look at `CollecitonUtils` class in `org.apache.commons`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe, is a set difference.

In C++, you could use [`std::set_difference`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/).

Answer (score 4):

No. A NAND operation works on two booleans. You have two lists.

This is called a difference or [complement](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29).

Comment: @pmr : since a set is defined as a collection of objects in set theory, I'd say a list qualifies as a set.

Comment: @Sander De Dycker: But afair/k, a list is commonly an ordered collection, whereas a set is not. A list may contain redundant values, a set not.

Comment: A list can contain the same item multiple times. A set is a collection of *distinct* objects.

Comment: @Sander A collection of distinct objects. This doesn't hold for lists as the unique requirement isn't encoded in the type. But for all practical purposes you are right. This question just doesn't strike me as utterly practical in the current wording.

Comment: @pmr (and others) : you're all quite right, and I stand corrected. I assumed the asker had lists without duplicates in mind, but that assumption might indeed have been incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

NAND, or not-and includes all the "bits" which are not in both sets. An upper limit is implied e.g. 7, 15, 31 or 63.  bits are a sorted set, of true/false values best modelled with a BitSet.

e.g.

```
set1 = {2,3,4,5,9}
set2 = {3,5,9,10}
and  = {3,5,9}
nand = {0,1,2,4,6,7,8,10,11 ... }
```

as binary it would like

```
set1 = 0b10 | 0b100 | 0b1000 | 0b10000 | 0b100000000
set2 = 0b100 | 0b1000 | 0b10000 | 0b100000000 | 0b10000000000
and  = 0b100 | 0b1000 | 0b10000 | 0b100000000
nand = 0b1 | 0b10 | 0b100 | 0b10000 | 0b100000 | 0b10000000 | 0b100000000 | etc
```

Comment: +1 for recognizing the correspondence of algorithms, even though the answer isn't "NAND". Bitwise, I think he's looking for A AND NOT B (`a & ~b`). I can see how that leads you to NAND.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `set_difference` but that requires both lists to be sorted. If they aren't sorted you can always do the obvious `O(n^2)` algorithm.